# Getting Swagger to work in Play2 Scala

Tags: scala, slick, playframework-2.2, swagger

I'm attempting to get Swagger working in a Play2 application. I've include the dependancy in build.sbt. `"com.wordnik" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.3.1"`
I've defined a series of routes.

```
GET     /api-docs                   controllers.ApiHelpController.getResources
GET     /api-docs/building           controllers.ApiHelpController.getResource(path = "/building")
GET     /building                   controllers.Application.building
```

I also have a model that pulls data from Slick and has annotations.

```
package models

import scala.slick.driver.SQLServerDriver.simple._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.db.DB
import play.api.Play.current
import Database.threadLocalSession

@XmlRootElement(name = "Building")
case class Building(@XmlElement(name = "BuildingCode") BuildingCode: String,
                    @XmlElement(name = "BuildingDescription") BuildingDescription: String)

object Building {

  lazy val database = Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource())
  implicit val BuildingReads = Json.reads[Building]
  implicit val BuildingWrites = Json.writes[Building]

  val BuildingTable = new Table[Building]("building"){
    def BuildingCode = column[String]("BuildingCode", O.PrimaryKey)
    def BuildingDescription = column[String]("BuildingDescription")
    def * = BuildingCode ~ BuildingDescription <> (Building.apply _, Building.unapply _)
  }

  def getAll: Seq[Building] = {
    database withSession {
      val q = Query(BuildingTable)
      q.list
    }
  }
}
```

Here is what my controller looks like.

```
object Application extends Controller {

  def building = Action {
    Ok(Json.toJson(Building.getAll))
  }

}
```

When I navigate to /api-docs the page renders.

```
{"apiVersion":"beta","swaggerVersion":"1.2"}
```

Then if I navigate to /api-docs/building nothing is rendered. Finally when I navigate to /building I receive the payload. I'm not sure what else I have to do for Swagger to generate it's data. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post your controller implementation?  The error is most likely due to missing/improper annotations.

Also, check out https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/tree/master/samples/scala-play2 for a good sample play2-swagger app.

Comment: I just added my controller implementation above.

Comment: I believe you need to add annotations at the top-level of the controller and for each method you want to document.  You also need to make sure the route for "/api-docs/building" is defined in the routes file.  Take a look at the link to the sample app I posted for guidance on how to do these things